# How to show default home as up indicator using support action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-toolbar

In my app I set the home as up indicator to a non-default drawable in some circumstances.  Sometimes the home as up indicator should be reset to the default icon after it has been changed.

I've tried using

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(0);
```

Which according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeAsUpIndicator(int)) says will use the theme default. When I do this, the application crashes with the following error:

```
05-15 11:12:03.160: E/AndroidRuntime(13021): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 11:12:03.160: E/AndroidRuntime(13021): Process: xxxxx.yyyyyy.zzzzzz, PID: 13021
05-15 11:12:03.160: E/AndroidRuntime(13021): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
05-15 11:12:03.160: E/AndroidRuntime(13021):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1233)
05-15 11:12:03.160: E/AndroidRuntime(13021):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:756)
05-15 11:12:03.160: E/AndroidRuntime(13021):    at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:402)
05-15 11:12:03.160: E/AndroidRuntime(13021):    at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)
05-15 11:12:03.160: E/AndroidRuntime(13021):    at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:319)
05-15 11:12:03.160: E/AndroidRuntime(13021):    at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:133)
05-15 11:12:03.160: E/AndroidRuntime(13021):    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setNavigationIcon(Toolbar.java:754)
05-15 11:12:03.160: E/AndroidRuntime(13021):    at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(ToolbarActionBar.java:176)
05-15 11:12:03.160: E/AndroidRuntime(13021):    at xxxxx.yyyyyy.zzzzzz.updateHomeIndicator(aaaaa.java:1711)
```

I know the theme default value is setup correctly, because if I never set a custom home as up indicator, the back arrow appears fine.  I am calling `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` before trying the `setHomeAsUpIndicator(0)` call.

I know I can always copy the default home as up indicator asset into my project and use that asset directly, but I would like to avoid this workaround if at all possible.

Thanks!

Zach

Edit:

I have also tried

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(null);
```

Which results in no icon being displayed whatsoever.

Comment: Why are you passing 0 instead of a boolean value?

Comment: The setHomeAsUpIndicator() API requires a drawable or an int resource id value.  There is no boolean paramater API that accomplishes this (as far as I know).

Comment: @CarlosJ read closer, it should work.  The documentation states: `If you pass 0 to this method, the default drawable from the theme will be used.`  This is perfectly valid according to the documentation, however, it appears that if you set a custom icon, you can't call it with zero afterwards to re-set it back to the default icon.  This must be a corner case with the API.

Comment: Also, note that it's `setHomeButtonEnabled()` that takes a boolean value, which it looks like is not the problem here.  The problem is with `setHomeAsUpIndicator()`.

Comment: I see.  Thanks Daniel.  That seems to be the case I'm seeing then, yes.

Comment: @Zach No problem.  Unfortunately, I have no idea why this would not work.  It appears that once you set a custom indicator, the method will then expect a valid resource from then on.

Comment: I'd solve it by storing the default drawable inside a local var as `Drawable defaultUpIndicator = toolbar.getNavigationIcon()`, and if I want to restore the default icon, I'd use this variable `toolbar.setNavigationIcon(defaultUpIndicator)`.

Answer (score 0):

I follow the source code of: [ToolbarActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.1_r1/android/support/v7/internal/app/ToolbarActionBar.java)

And when I see the source code of: [ContextCompat.getDrawable()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.java#ContextCompat.getDrawable%28android.content.Context%2Cint%29), it says: "The value 0 is an invalid identifier".

```
 /**
 * Return a drawable object associated with a particular resource ID.
 * <p>
 * Starting in {@link android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#LOLLIPOP}, the returned
 * drawable will be styled for the specified Context's theme.
 *
 * @param id The desired resource identifier, as generated by the aapt tool.
 *            This integer encodes the package, type, and resource entry.
 *            The value 0 is an invalid identifier.
 * @return Drawable An object that can be used to draw this resource.
 */
public static final Drawable getDrawable(Context context, int id) {
    final int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (version >= 21) {
        return ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(context, id);
    } else {
        return context.getResources().getDrawable(id);
    }
}
```

And I keep follow the source code, and I see below code finally, this is where you exception throw: [Resources.getValue()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.1_r1/android/content/res/Resources.java#Resources.getValue%28int%2Candroid.util.TypedValue%2Cboolean%29)

```
/**
 * Return the raw data associated with a particular resource ID.
 * 
 * @param id The desired resource identifier, as generated by the aapt
 *           tool. This integer encodes the package, type, and resource
 *           entry. The value 0 is an invalid identifier.
 * @param outValue Object in which to place the resource data.
 * @param resolveRefs If true, a resource that is a reference to another
 *                    resource will be followed so that you receive the
 *                    actual final resource data.  If false, the TypedValue
 *                    will be filled in with the reference itself.
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException Throws NotFoundException if the given ID does not exist.
 *
 */
public void getValue(int id, TypedValue outValue, boolean resolveRefs)
        throws NotFoundException {
    boolean found = mAssets.getResourceValue(id, 0, outValue, resolveRefs);
    if (found) {
        return;
    }
    throw new NotFoundException("Resource ID #0x"
                                + Integer.toHexString(id));
}
```

Up to now, I can't see any special handling to the '0'. So, I think that's a bug in the official document you post above. The easy way to solve this crash error is to use a existing identifier, just like your default icon id.